# Como checar se uma String está vazia em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Dado o seguinte objeto:

```
var pessoa = {
      nome: "fernando"
}
```

Obs.: às vezes estou recebendo o objeto da seguinte forma:

```
var pessoa = {
      nome: ""
}
```

Como faço para verificar se o atributo **nome** está vazio, como mostra o segundo objeto?

Comment: @Phanpy porque a insistência de editar a palavra vazio para "vázio", com acento?!

Comment: @Phanpy mas de qual português "vázio" é correto?

Comment: @Phanpy Tem certeza? Veja: http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/v%C3%A1zio/

Comment: @Phanpy antes de alterar qualquer que seja a pergunta ou resposta, tenha certeza no que estará fazendo. Qualquer coisa, recorra aqui e veja sobre o [privilégio de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Eu considero a forma mais prática:

```
if (!pessoa.nome)
```

Pois vai verificar:

- `vazio ("")`
- `null`
- `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `false`
- `0`

```js
var pessoa = {
      nome: ""
}

if (!pessoa.nome)
  console.log("Atributo vazio");
```

Answer (score 6):

Existem três maneiras de checar isso.

`if (pessoa.nome === "") {}`

ou

`if (!pessoa.nome) {}`

ou

`if (pessoa.nome.length === 0) {}`

Answer (score 4):

Length verifica quantos caracteres tem.

```
if(pessoa.nome.length == 0)
```

Se tiver 0 é porquê está vazio.

Ou pode usar exclamação `!` para verificar se é falso, se for `true` é porquê sempre tem caracteres.

### Exemplo

```js
var pessoa = {
  nome_1 : 'Teste',
  nome_2 : ''
};

if(pessoa.nome_1.length == 0) console.log('Vazio');
if(pessoa.nome_2.length == 0) console.log('Vazio');

if(!pessoa.nome_1.length) console.log('Vazio');    
if(!pessoa.nome_2.length) console.log('Vazio');
```

Comment: Qual o problema da minha resposta ? O código está errado ?

Comment: Nenhum problema. +1

Comment: Aqui deu certo.

Comment: acho que é intriga da oposição rs +1