# Problema com acesso a propriedades de "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo uma variável que busca uma `input` e a partir disso ela trabalha obtendo informações dela.

O problema que me surge é que quando a input não está lá, o script **para** dizendo que não pode acessar propriedades de algo indefinido: ***Cannot read property '0' of undefined***.

Como ignorar isso ou simplesmente fazer uma checagem para que meu script **não pare**? No PHP eu faria algo com `isset` mas no JavaScript não tenho idéia...

```
files = $(".X"); 
if (files[0].files.length >= 1) { 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar se ele existe antes de tentar acessá-lo:

```
files = $(".X"); 
if (files[0]){
  if (files[0].files.length >= 1) { 
    //...
  }
}
```

`if (files[0])` irá retornar *true* se não cair em nenhuma dessas condições [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173221/como-checar-se-uma-string-est%C3%A1-vazia-em-javascript/173226#173226).

Answer (score 2):

Percebi que você está usando JQuery. Isto significa que o retorno do seletor sempre irá retornar um [objeto](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) (uma *"espécie"* de array/collection), ainda que o selector não encontre nada (isto ocorre para permitir um encadeamento de métodos). Então não daria para fazer uma comparação com `== null` ou `type of === undefined`.

Contudo, neste objeto, temos a propriedade `.length`.

Então você pode checar se seu seletor retornou algo ou não checando esta propriedade. Ficaria algo assim:

```
var files = $(".X");

if (files.length > 0) {
    /* seu código */
}
```

Traduzindo da [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery):

> O objeto jQuery se comporta como um array; possui uma propriedade
>   `length` e os elementos no seu objeto podem ser acessados pelos seus
>   índices numéricos `[0]` a `[length-1]`. Note que um objeto jQuery não é
>   atualmente uma Array JavaScript, então ele não possui todos os métodos
>   de uma Array verdadeira, como o método `join()`.
>
> (...)
>
> **Um objeto jQuery pode ser vazio**, contendo nenhum elemento.