# Pegar valor diferente de null javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma função em Javascript, e de toda forma que eu coloco ele entra na função, eu quero que ele não entre se o valor tiver null, pois está dando erro. Ele só precisa entrar na função se anexo for diferente de nulo. 
Segue como estou fazendo:

```js
   $(function () {
            if (document.getElementById("Anexo").value != "" || document.getElementById("Anexo").value != undefined || document.getElementById("Anexo").value != null) {
                $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                    var f = this.files[0]

                    if (f.size > 8388608 || f.fileSize > 8388608) {
                        alert("Tamanho excede o limite permitido.")

                        this.value = null;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

De qualquer forma que eu coloco, ele me retorna sempre o erro nesta linha:

> $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {

Se o Anexo ta preenchido não retorna erro, porém pode acontecer do mesmo estar vazio. E não pode retornar erro, por isso estou tentando utilizar o if.

Edição: Depois de muitas tentativas, cheguei no seguiente erro:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>   Que ocorre nesta linha: 
>    $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {

Utilizo a linguagem Asp.net C#.
Anexo é um componente FileUpload, este erro ocorre só quando o componente está vazio, por isso precisaria verificar se o mesmo está nulo para realizar a função.

Edição: Tentei colocando numa variável, dessa forma:

```js
var label = document.getElementById("<%=Anexo.ClientID%>");
```

Quando declaro na variável, ai ele me dá o erro nesta linha, e o mesmo erro de:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Na sua condição, tente fazer: `if (document.getElementById("Anexo") && document.getElementById("Anexo").value) { ... }`

Comment: Acontece o mesmo problema, continua acontecendo o erro na mesma linha.

Comment: Então, por favor, edite a pergunta e descreva melhor seu problema, preferencialmente criando um [mcve], pois está complicado entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Mesmo Anexo estando nulo, ele entra nessa função, no caso se estivesse nulo não poderia entrar, e de toda forma q eu coloco != null != undefined  != "" ele sempre entra na função.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como checar se uma String está vazia em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173221/como-checar-se-uma-string-est%c3%a1-vazia-em-javascript)

Comment: Como editado @LucasCosta o problema não está só na verificação do componente vazio, tanto que quando declaro o componente, o erro ocorre nele. Tanto que já tentei várias formas, e não da certo, inclusive a do exemplo.

Comment: @marianac_costa Da maneira que você vez a pergunta originalmente, dizendo que o erro estava no JavaScript, gerou respostas que resolveriam o problema relatado, assim como seria duplicata da pergunta que o Lucas citou. Te aconselho a criar outra pergunta focando o problema no C#.

Comment: Mas o erro ocorre na função javascript, colocar o if para verificar se estava vazio, foi uma solução que pensei que poderia dar certo, mais infelizmente todas as respostas que me foi dada, nenhuma resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Tentou `if ( document.getElementById("Anexo").value ) {` @marianac_costa? Se ele entrar mesmo assim, coloque um `console.log( document.getElementById("Anexo").value )` antes de `$('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change` pra ver se o anexo está vazio mesmo ou não.

Comment: Fiz o teste, dessa forma @LucasCosta, o valor que apareceu foi: undefined , continua dando o mesmo erro na linha Anexo.ClienteID.

Comment: Se está entrando quando undefined tem alguma confusão errada aí porque ele vai testar todas as condições que está na resposta que indiquei como duplicada. Teste com `if ( document.getElementById("Anexo").value != 'undefined ' )`

Comment: @LucasCosta eu fiz o teste igual vc informou, olha como coloquei:  var pessoa = {
                nome: document.getElementById("Anexo").value
            }

            if (!pessoa.nome){ Não sei se fiz certo. Porem ele continua dando erro no mesmo lugar!

Comment: Está errado. O pessoa da outra resposta é só um exemplo, e você está negando a condição. Tente exatamente `if ( document.getElementById("Anexo").value ) {` no lugar do seu if. Se entrar mesmo assim tente `if ( document.getElementById("Anexo").value != 'undefined' ) {`. Se entrar mesmo assim, crie um exemplo vericavél pra nós @marianac_costa, por favor.

Comment: O erro está no .NET, não no JavaScript. É o objeto `Anexo` do .NET que não existe. Nenhuma solução resolveu o problema porque você pediu algo do JavaScript, mas o problema não está nele. Entenda isso.

Comment: Sim @AndersonCarlosWoss depois de muito estudo, descobri o problema, mas realmente a parte de java, me ajudou muito do IF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando esta condição:

```
if (obj.value != "" || obj.value != null || obj.value != undefined) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

A condição será verdadeira quando:

1. `obj.value` for diferente de `""`; **ou**
2. `obj.value` for diferente de `null`; **ou**
3. `obj.value` for diferente de `undefined`;

Então, se o valor for uma *string* vazia, a condição 2 é satisfeita e o código é executado:

```js
const obj = {"value": ""};

if (obj.value != "" || obj.value != null || obj.value != undefined) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

Se o valor for nulo, a condição 1 é satisfeita e o código é executado:

```js
const obj = {"value": null};

if (obj.value != "" || obj.value != null || obj.value != undefined) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

Já, se o valor for indefinido, a condição 1 também é satisfeita e o código é executado:

```js
const obj = {"value": undefined};

if (obj.value != "" || obj.value != null || obj.value != undefined) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

E, por fim, se o valor não existir um erro será disparado.

```js
const obj = undefined;

if (obj.value != "" || obj.value != null || obj.value != undefined) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

Acredito que nenhuma das opções acima deveria fazer o código executar, então faça:

```
if (obj && obj.value) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

Pois assim, se o objeto não existir, o primeiro operando da expressão retornará falso. Já, se o atributo `value` do objeto não existir ou ser nulo, o segundo operando retornará falso. Veja abaixo todos os testes anteriores sobre esta condição:

```js
const tests = [
  {"value": ""},
  {"value": null},
  {"value": undefined},
  undefined
];

for (obj of tests) {
  if (obj && obj.value) {
    console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
  }
}
```

Perceba que o código não é executado em todos os testes. Porém, se definir um valor para o atributo:

```js
const obj = {"value": "foo"};

if (obj && obj.value) {
  console.log("Condição foi satisfeita");
}
```

O código é executado.

Comment: vou fazer os testes, obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia Anderson, de toda forma que coloco, continua dando erro na mesma linha: $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () { Se estivesse vazio ele não deveria entrar, não sei porque ele entrar e dá o erro nesta linha. O erro que ele dá é: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Ah, então o seu problema não está no JavaScript. Que linguagem é esta que está utilizando? De onde vem este valor `Anexo`? Por quê esta mensagem de erro não estava na pergunta desde o início?

Comment: Anderson, depois de muitas mudanças que cheguei neste erro, ainda não editei a pergunta pois só consegui verificar agora. Anexo, é um fileUpload, utilizo na linguagem C# Asp.Net.

Comment: Então coloque seu código C# na pergunta e a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: Por trás do Anexo (fileupload) não possui código, o erro dá nessa parte do JavaScript, já editei a pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Em que parte do código você define a variável `Anexo`?

Comment: Anexo é o ID do componente FileUpload. Então não declaro ele, utilizo o valor do componente, você acha que se declarasse para pegar o valor, seria mais viável ?

Comment: É um componente no C# ou no HTML/JS? O que seria este `ClientId`?

Comment: é um componente do C#, ClientID fornece o valor para o atributo " id " do HTML da tag HTML desse controle de servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Faltou alguns `;` no seu código. Também tem problema na sua verificação, se o `value` fosse `null` a verificação `document.getElementById("Anexo").value != ""` iria retornar `true`, e como você estava usando o `||`(ou), se qualquer uma das verificações retornasse `true` a resposta seria `true`. Então substitui o `||`(ou) por `&&`(e). Ou seja, a resposta será `true` somente se todas as verificações retornarem `true`:

```
$(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("Anexo").value != "" && 
        document.getElementById("Anexo").value != undefined && 
        document.getElementById("Anexo").value != null) {
            $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                var f = this.files[0];
                if (f.size > 8388608 || f.fileSize > 8388608) {
                    alert("Tamanho excede o limite permitido.");
                    this.value = null;
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Isso não parece resolver o problema. Se o valor for `null`, a primeira condição, `value != ""`, será satisfeita, então entra no `if`.

Comment: Continua com o mesmo problema, o erro ocorre sempre nesta linha " $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {", o if parece não funcionar, coloquei no console do google, para verificar o valor quando está vazio, e aparece assim: document.getElementById("Anexo").value
""

Comment: Bem observado @AndersonCarlosWoss, vou alterar a resposta

Comment: @RobertoFagundes cai no mesmo erro, e não funciona o resto da função, mesmo quando insiro um arquivo dentro do padrão;

Comment: 1) deve usar o && and e não o || ou. 2) após a condição não se faz um função que aguarda uma nova ação do usuário. 3) recupere em variáveis as informações dinâmicas para que possa verificar se tem conteúdo. var xpto 
= '<%=Anexo.ClientID %>';

Comment: @WilsonRosaGomes Eu fiz dessa forma, troquei por && e continuou o mesmo problema, ele me informa este erro Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto, nesta linha: $('#<%=Anexo.ClientID %>').change(function () {.No debug do Google Chrome, ele me retorna o valor "", ou seja vazio.

Comment: @marianac_costa teria como postar seu código html, você está usando asp classic <%=Anexo.ClientID%>, se sim, poste também o arquivo.asp. Pois como mencionei não se deve usar uma função que espera ação do usuário dentro de uma condição IF.