# Tem como tirar a palavra "null" e só escrever na tela "palavra não encontrada" ? (Usando o match)

Tags: javascript, funções, match

> Isso é o que eu tentei fazer, mas fica aparecendo:

aula 46 do curso de javascript

null

Palavra não encontrada

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Match - Procura elemento </title> 
        <script>
    
        function carrega(){
           var texto = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
           var res = texto.match("html");
           document.write(texto+"</br></br>");
           document.write(res+"</br>");
           
           
           if(res == null){
             document.write("Palavra não encontrada");
           }else{
            document.write("Encontrou: "+res.length+" Palavra");
            }
           }
           window.addEventListener("load",carrega);
           
           
        </script>
</head>
<body>
      <p id="txt">aula 46 do curso de javascript</p>
</body>
</html>
```

> O Resultado tem que ser :

aula 46 do curso de javascript

Palavra não encontrada

Answer (score 0):

É só verificar se `res` dentro de uma estrutura de decisão, exemplo:

```
if (res) document.write(res + "</br>");
```

Código completo:

```js
function carrega() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
  var res = texto.match("html");
  document.write(texto + "</br></br>");
  if (res) document.write(res + "</br>");


  if (res == null) {
    document.write("Palavra não encontrada");
  } else {
    document.write("Encontrou: " + res.length + " Palavra");
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", carrega);
```

```html
<p id="txt">aula 46 do curso de javascript</p>
```

em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) `null` é falso na estrutura de decisão (isso é característica da própria linguagem), por isso foi verificado da forma mais simples, mas, também pode colocar assim:

```
if (res !== null)
```

que tem o mesmo resultado da outra estrutura. Realmente tem que tomar cuidado com `Javascript` se tiver certeza do retorno pode ser feito assim, se não tem que fazer outras verificações.

<sup>Referencias</sup>

- [Pegar valor diferente de null javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221892/pegar-valor-diferente-de-null-javascript)
- [How do I check for null values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)
- [How to determine if variable is undefined or null in JavaScript](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null-in-javascript.php)

Comment: Obrigado, deu o resultado que eu queria.

Comment: Mas eu só não entendi muito o que quer dizer isso : if (res) document.write(res + "</br>");

Comment: Dei um complementada @Dereguepinto é uma característica do `Javascript` esse tipo de comparação em resultados que podem vir `null`.

Answer (score 0):

> Fiquei tentando aqui , e deu certo desse jeito :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Match - Procura elemento </title> 
        <script>
    
        function carrega(){
           var texto = document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
           var res = texto.match("curso");
           document.write(texto+"</br></br>");
           
           if(res == null){
             document.write("Palavra não encontrada");
           }else{
            document.write(res+"</br>");
            document.write("Encontrou: "+res.length+" Palavra");
            }
           }
           window.addEventListener("load",carrega);
           
        </script>
</head>
<body>
      <p id="txt">aula 46 do curso de javascript</p>
</body>
</html>
```