# Como verificar se existe ou não um rel=""

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Estou montando uma função para o wordpress, em que a pessoa pode navegar entre os post através do keyboard.

Com dificuldades, consegui criar a seguinte função:

```
   <script>
        window.onkeydown = function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 38) { //Para cima

                if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) { 
                    var href =  $("a[rel='next']").attr("href");                 
                    window.location.href = href;
                }

            }
            if (event.keyCode === 40) { //Para baixo

                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) { 

                    var href =  $("a[rel='prev']").attr("href");                 
                    window.location.href = href;
                }
            }            

        };
    </script>
```

Contudo, precisava de verificar antes se existe no html um rel="prev" ou rel="next" para assim, liberar ou não a função do keydown

por exemplo:

Se existe um `rel="prev"` no html, então roda a função para mudar de página ao apertar o botão no teclado.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar obter o elemento usando o jQuery, se for diferente de nulo é porque o elemento existe.

### Exemplo

```js
//para executar apos o DOM ser carregado
$(document).ready(function(){
   let prev = $('[rel="prev"]'),
       next = $('[rel="next"]');

   if (prev.length) console.log("Tem prev");
   if (next.length) console.log("Tem next");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input rel="prev">
```

Comment: Ola @lucas costa, obrigado, mas consegui de uma forma mais simples:    if ($("a[rel='prev']").length > 0) {

Comment: Que bom! É basicamente a mesma coisa @ThallysonDias, na verdade `if (prev.length)` é mais simples que `if ($("a[rel='prev']").length > 0)`, como você pode ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173221/como-checar-se-uma-string-est%c3%a1-vazia-em-javascript/173226#173226)